# ggplot: Adding horizontal lines to each bar + repositioning tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having some difficulty with two aspects of formatting when using ggplot.

The first, I want to be able to add horizontal lines to each of the bars so that bars look like this:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [eurosurveillance.org](http://www.eurosurveillance.org/images/dynamic/ew/v05n47/Legionella%20Norway%20epi%20curve.gif))</sub>

The second, I want to change the position of tick labels so that they fall between each bar so that labels look like this

[image: img]

What I have so far:

```
values=runif(50,0,20)
sex=rep(c("Male","Female"),25)

df=data.frame(values,sex)

label=c("","0-5","5-10","10-15","15-20")
sep=seq(0,20,5)

ggplot(df, aes(x = values,fill=sex))+geom_bar(binwidth=5,colour="black")+
scale_x_discrete(breaks=sep,labels=label,limits=sep)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice description and reproducible example!

Axis labels centered on the bars are the default if your x-axis is a factor. Since you know your binwidths, just use `cut` to do the binning for you:

```
df$cutval <- cut(values, breaks = seq(0, 20, by = 5))
ggplot(df, aes(x = cutval, fill = sex)) +
    geom_bar(colour = "black", width = 1)
```

To get the labels exactly as in your example, you can do a little regex editing:

```
library(stringr)
# delete open parens and closing brackets
levels(df$cutval) <- str_replace_all(levels(df$cutval), "\\(|\\]", "")
# replace comma with tilde
levels(df$cutval) <- str_replace_all(levels(df$cutval), "\\,", "~")
```

yielding

```
> levels(df$cutval)
[1] "0~5"   "5~10"  "10~15" "15~20"
```

[image]

To get the boxes (all those horizontal lines), you can use a grouping variable (we'll need to reorder first). Can't say I love the look but here it is:

```
df <- df[order(df$cutval, df$sex), ]
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
ggplot(df, aes(x = cutval, fill=sex, group = id)) +
    geom_bar(colour = "black", width = 1)
```

[image]